# How to find future UTC offset based on specific date and time zone name using Angular?

Tags: javascript

Is there an equivalent for figuring out UTC offset by supplying date, time, time zone name using Angular? This is very easy in C# - example below:

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Eastern Standard Time");

string dateInput = "2022-11-15";
var parsedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateInput);
TimeSpan offset = tzi.GetUtcOffset(parsedDate); // this returns -5

string dateInput2 = "2022-03-20";
var parsedDate2 = DateTime.Parse(dateInput2);
TimeSpan offset2 = tzi.GetUtcOffset(parsedDate2); // this returns -4
```

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript getTimezoneOffset() method is used to find the timezone offset

```js
let d = new Date(Date.parse("2022-03-21T06:38:30+0000"));
console.log(d.getTimezoneOffset()) // 120 minutes offset for me
```

Comment: I think the issue I am having is that if I am "my browser" in EST right now -4 and I pass in GMT +1 lets say for 11/16/2022, the function new Date(Date.parse("11/16/2022, 4:00:00 PM GMT +1")) returns EST -5 not GMT +1. It like ignores it completely. This does not happen in C#. I tried all kinds of things so far and no luck. Its possible that the string we pass to Date.parse has to be in a specific format. Thanks

Comment: Date string isn't a special format, regular ISO string. `getTimezoneOffset()` returns the timezone difference in minutes, between the UTC and the current local time. Just be careful as getTimezoneOffset() would not count for daylight saving. Also timeZone offset is not UTC offset. Dates in javascript suck. Getting a offset from Date obj is no easy feat. I honestly, I would recommend using a library for dates (e.g Luxon) to avoid mistakes. Otherwise just regex it. https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-get-the-users-time-zone-and-offset-in-javascript-da53adb27f32

Comment: It's super inconvenient to the point where it makes me want to create an API call in C# to get all the info or reference a custom date key table of some sort which would have all the settings including daylight savings time. I am able to get proper offset using getTimezoneOffset(), its just it only works for my time zone, not a custom one I am trying to use. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

After many hours spent on this I decided to give moment.js as suggested by Joosep.P to try some library and also by others. The below seems to work as expected. What is bizarre is if you try to use timezoneName other than where you currently are and if you debug, you will still see your own time zone name for the date, however the offset will be calculated correctly. I assume that this works because of proper setting .tz call.

```
var timezoneName = 'America/New_York';
var dateInput = '2022-11-15';
var parsedDate = moment.tz(dateInput, timezoneName);
var offseta = parsedDate.utcOffset()/60; // this returns -5
var offsetb = moment.tz(dateInput, timezoneName).format('Z'); // returns '-05:00' as a string

var dateInput2 = '2022-03-20';
var parsedDate2 = moment.tz(dateInput2, timezoneName);
var offset2a = parsedDate2.utcOffset()/60; // this returns -4
var offset2b = moment.tz(dateInput2, timezoneName).format('Z'); // returns '-04:00' as a string
```